# Identifying an SMD diode

Tags: pcb, diodes, identification, surface-mount

I have a small PCB from an automotive button.

I would like some help to identify the diode. I am not finding a lot if I search for 1429. My multimeter in diode mode gives 740 mV (diode in situ).

Since it is automotive it's all likely to be 12 volts DC.

The device is functional, but I wish to make another of these with a different shape PCB, and so need to source each of the components on here separately.

[image: PCB with diode]

Comment: If the multimeter is showing the voltage drop across the diode in millivolts, 740 mV is an entirely reasonable value for a working diode. Do you suspect something is wrong with it?

Comment: It's is functional but I wish to make another of these with a different shape PCB, so need to source each of the components on here separately

Comment: Have you worked out all the connections between the components and drawn a circuit diagram? Once you've done that, you will be able to see what specifications are needed for each component; with that information you can pick ones that you can obtain from an ordinary electronic components supplier.

Comment: I haven't but I will do that. The resistors are easy, the LEDs should also be easy, so really this diode is all that is left, but a diagram makes sense

Comment: Can you give more pictures? It's really hard to figure what is the ground and power from only that.

Answer (score 1):

This diode seems to be a reverse polarity protection diode. I think when you plug the wrong way, it shorts the battery to save the rest of the board. If so, you can probably replace this diode by any diode with a forward voltage lower then your battery voltage and a current sufficient to handle the battery discharge rate.

Comment: As it's an automotive application, I suspect that shorting the battery will not end well for the diode, assuming it lasts longer than the thin traces it is connected to.

Comment: I only see the trace and the silkscreen. From it, I have some confidence that this diode have it's anode on the ground. If it's not a reverse polarity protection, it his a Zener diode, but I find it odd for the package. It seems like a rectifying diode. Thus my conclusion that it is probably a reverse polarity protection.

Comment: It's the "shorts the battery" part that I am suspicious of. I would have thought that a reverse-polarity protection diode is more likely to be in series (blocks reverse current, creates a small voltage drop) with the circuit rather than anti-parallel to it (explodes under reverse-polarity condition).

Comment: There are several topologies. Usually, placing a diode in series is the best way to go, but you loose vfoward on your supply. On battery application it is very significant. So you prefer emptying the battery to protect yourself then loosing power in your general operation (It's not an ideal way but on a budget, it might be the best of both world).

Comment: The connector does not allow it to be fitted incorrectly. The middle LED is a button backlight, and the bottom left LED is the on/off indicator. I can provide info for the connector pins if it helps (on the reverse of the board, the 4 solder blobs for them are at the bottom)

Comment: @Julien It's an automotive application. The battery is capable of melting a screwdriver, so using a diode that size to short the battery is not going to be useful.

Comment: @AndrewMorton There's two categories of automotive reverse polarity protection. The first is transient pulses from coupling. These are microsecond pulses at around -100 V, see ISO7637-2. The second is long-term reverse polarity protection (60 s, -14 V), which is a newer requirement. If there's no ICs on the switch, this device may be able to perfectly withstand the battery misconnect case, leaving only transient protection necessary.

Comment: @user71659 What would happen to an SMD diode wired directly in series with a car battery? Not a transient condition, diode anode connected to battery +ve, cathode connected directly to battery -ve (with whatever resistance the wiring presents). That is what is being suggested in this answer, unless I am completely misreading "it shorts the battery".

Comment: @AndrewMorton Your arguments are forgetting that this device is not connected with 2/0 by the battery. There's wiring which has pretty significant resistance, and a fuse. The key is the short-circuit current available at the device.

Comment: @user71659 What current do you think would be reasonably available? 20 A for a few tens of seconds until a fuse blows?

Comment: @AndrewMorton 28 AWG copper is .2 ohms/m, so let's call it an ohm, also including connectors. That means at 14 V, that's 14 A of instantaneous fault current. Let's look at a standard [ATOF fuse](https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/automotive/datasheets/fuses/passenger-car-and-commercial-vehicle/blade-fuses/littelfuse_atof_datasheet.pdf), a 5 A fuse will fault at 14 A in less than 200 ms. So that's the answer.

Comment: @user71659 What if we take it as 16 AWG copper, as in fairly typical car wire, and a 15 A fuse because it's in parallel with the 12 V auxillary power outlet? I'm just saying it seems ridiculous to try and short a car battery instead of using a simple series diode to protect against accidental reverse polarity when installing the device.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Nonsensical argument. That's why you don't put a 15 A fuse on a switch. The engineers chose the fuse and protection specifically for the load. That's called engineering design. This is why your car has a 50+ fuses. If you need to put something on a high-current circuit, then you put better protection on it. Common sense! If you're going to make a stupid design, then you will have failures. You're saying, hey I put a 60 A dryer breaker on my bedroom outlets and my house burned down. What did you expect?

Comment: @user71659 Let's see if the OP adds a circuit diagram to the question. Maybe me assuming the switch is an after-market part, and thus not subject to the car designer's sense, is unreasonable.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The other part you're ignoring is, as I previously mentioned, the requirement to handle induced negative transients. Shunting induced current to ground is desired as it will limit the peak voltage.

Comment: @user71659 Wouldn't a series diode block those transients?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The diode would need a much higher breakdown voltage, withstanding the peak transient voltage. This is why ESD and surge protection uses a shunt configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The markings match with a [ROHM 1SR154-400](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811021918_ROHM-Semicon-1SR154-400TE25_C24002.pdf) rectifier diode.

[image]

[image]
(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Diodes-General-Purpose_ROHM-Semicon-1SR154-400TE25_C24002.html))

The font doesn't match a 100%, but maybe it changed a bit over time. Here is another diode (1SR154-600) from the same series with a matching font:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the comment you mention that you want to reproduce this circuit? If that so, why don't you use a semi-conductor identifier (like Atlas DCA55) to identify the parameters of the diode. Use the form factor to evaluate the current rating and hope for the best? If you don't have access to a semi-conductor identifier, you can desolder it and plug it on a variable power supply and check it's curve on both side and identify it's current characteristics.